# Python append string to list without mentioning list

Tags: python

I have a problem in Python:

**I want to add a string to a list, but the last name is in the form of a string, is this even possible?**

I already tried the exec() functions, but that gave me only errors:

```
ListA = ["a", "b"]
X = "ListA"
L = "c"
print(ListA)

{append to list A, without mentioning list a}
```

**I want the output to be:**

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

is there a function like:

```
X.append(L)
```

to which, it appends to ListA?

Comment: Can you make the string into a list using the `list()` function?

Comment: This seems like quite an unusual thing to want to do - what is the context of explicitly saying `ListA` being an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "ListA" is a global variable, you can do 
    `globals()[X].append(L)`

Answer (score 1):

You can `eval` the list name and then append the value:

```py
eval(X).append(L)
print(ListA)  # ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ListA = ["a", "b"]

X = "ListA"

L = "c"

globals()[X].append(L)
print(ListA)
```